# How to point the child class pointer to the base class pointer?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

```
class A {
public:
    void show() {
        cout << "Class A Show"<<'\n';
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void show() {
        cout << "Class C Show" << '\n';
    }
};

int main()  //first int main()
{
    C* a = new C;  //line 1
    a->show();     //line 2
    a = new A(); //line 3
    a->show();   //line 4
}

int main()  //2nd int main()
{
    A* a = new C;  //line 1
    a->show();     //line 2
    a = new A(); //line 3
    a->show();   //line 4
}
```

**Question :**

Output of each line in both int main () when rum separately

**Error**
A value of Type "A*" cannot be assigned to a value of Type "C*"

I came across a interview question where the panel asked the outputs of the mentioned 2 int mains() and asked if it produces an error than how can we omit that error. I tried this code on compiler and the **error came on line 3 of First int main()** while **2nd int main() ran without an error**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the first main type of `a` is `C*` since you cannot store there `A*`, because `C` is derived from `A`, not vice versa

Comment: O how can i remove this error

Comment: If the question is *how to remove the error* the answer is *fix the code*

Comment: @ShivaChandel You can't remove this error because what that `main` is trying to do is conceptually flawed.

Comment: Note that there is no polymorphism here because `show` is not `virtual`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It reminds me of an old doctor joke, when patient comes to doctors office and asks the good doctor: *Doctor, it pains me when I bend like that (and does really bizzare and obviously painful twist), what's your advice on how to avoid such a pain?* And the good doctor replies: *"Just don't bend like that, my dear!"*

Comment: I think he’s asking for help in deciphering what errors go wrong and why, and how we should prevent it.

Comment: We know that every herring is a fish, but not every fish is a herring. You have two classes, class Fish and class Herring. (1) What would be a natural relationship between them? (a) Fish inherits Herring (b) Herring inherits Fish (c) both a and b (d) neither a nor b? Why? (2) Given the answer to (1) and these two statements `Fish* fish = new Herring; Herring* herring = new Fish;` which is correct? (a) first (b) second (c) both (d) neither? Why?

Comment: @n.m. a class RedHerring would have templated type cast operator to any type  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a strictly typed language, so you cannot assign value of one type to value of another. Pointers to different types are different types. There is concept of compatible types which can be converted implicitly, but pointers to different types aren't one of them.

Now assigning pointer to derived class to pointer of base class is allowed. From abstact point of view, an object if class-child of type A is an object of class-type A. Such assignment is part of the type erasure paradigm. But opposite is not possible, because type A is not type C.